# Oracle: built in SQL pretty-print?

Tags: oracle

Oracle has some packages that will dump objects in SQL format, such as `dbms_metadata.set_transform_param`.  One option that can be set is to "pretty print" the SQL.

Is there anything in Oracle that will pretty print a random SQL query string?  Something like:

```
select pretty_print('select * from emp;') sql from dual;

sql
---
'select *
   from emp;'
```

Comment: As in you want a randomly generated string of a variable length that is returned in a pretty print format?

Comment: @AliRazeghi, yes that would be perfect.

Comment: There is no such feature inside the database. Oracle's SQL client "SQL Developer" can do that though

Comment: If the given SQL will correctly parse ok in your current database, you might be able to use `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` to get it into the shared pool without executing it, then use `DBMS_METADATA` to pretty print it. Obviously won't work if the statement won't parse in the current session due to missing objects.

Comment: Just don't parse a DDL using dbms_sql.parse. IIRC it would execute it unless behavior changed in recent versions.